# Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Crashes when I add arrays brackets

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, crash

I'm getting a weird chrash in VS ultimate 2013. When I try to add array brackets (`[]`) i my code, VS instantly stops responding and crashes without any info. It only does that when I'm in a solution : if I open the same file I was working on before in VS, but without the rest of the solution, there is no problem. I tried rebouting my computer and disabling  all extensions, still no luck. It only happens in that specific soluton too.

***EDIT : *** After diging around I came to the conclusion that it only happened after I add a user component I wrote myself. This component uses a DLL I took from the internet, and if I remove any references to that DLL from my component, I no longer get the problem. Unfortunatly I need that DLL to do my program.

Comment: Do you have any addons installed like style cops? I used to have horrible issues whenever I tried spellchecker addons.

Comment: As I said in my question I have tried disabling all add-ons, still didn't work.

Comment: I've had various problems over the years that have been solved by deleting the .suo or .sdf files.  (Keep a backup, obviously.)

Comment: I would try actually uninstalling them and/or removing any files that they may have created in the solution folder. If it's also that specific solution as you said, try creating a new solution and re-adding the projects. This is a very odd problem that not many people have possibly had.

Comment: Tried removing DLL references I did earlier on : no luck.
Tried creating a new solution and adding the project : still crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally a solution :

The DLL I said I was using was hooking itself to the keyboard to capture the keypresses (I need to do global hotkeys). It seams that since I asked the the DLL to hook itself in the constructor of the component, it was hooking itself to the keyboard when as soon as I was adding the component to my form (components' and and controls' constructor are executed when they are added to a form), therefore creating trouble when I pressed the key combinaison to input a `[]`. (I'm using canadian french keyboard, I have to press Ctrl + Alt + ` to input that character)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running Visual Studio in safe mode? You can run it in safe mode by using "devenv /SafeMode"